# Why partial methods can only have void return type?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, partial-methods

what is the reason /logic/obstacle behind the fact that partial methods can only have void return type?

thanks

Comment: How do you expect a partial method with a non void return type to work? Should they return `default(T)` or what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Partial methods are designed to be left out if you did not provide an implementation for them. The compiler actually removes calls to partial methods that are not implemented.

This also highlights why they cannot return anything: If you relied on a return value without implementing the partial method, then what? You'd have something uninitialised, despite the code clearly showing an assignment.

Similarly, methods that use the [Conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute) attribute can only return `void` for the same reason. The method call may or may not exist in the compiled IL.

Comment: Finally understood with your post. Had difficulty finding the answer elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with throwing a compile error if there's no implementation?

Comment: @AustinWBryan, then you might end up with compile errors in generated code. Or the code generator has to effectively do the job of the compiler by looking at all your code to see  whether you have an implementation of the partial method to potentially leave out the call to it.

Comment: @Joey I see. I guess it's a bit of a shame, because I thought this could be used to mimic the C++ .cpp/.h files where you could use the .h as sort've a "table of contents" and get a quick viewing of the class, and maybe putting the xml comments there, so you don't have use so many lines for comments in the implementation files

Comment: Since C# 9.0 from 2020, `partial` methods do not have to return `void`. Edit: I wrote that with some references in an answer in the linked thread.

Answer (score 3):

Implementation of partial methods are intended as optional.

If the implementation is not provided, a call is still valid, but will be silently removed by the compiler.  A delegate can only be assigned a partial methods which is implemented.

This means that they should have no side effects - effectively no return values or "out" parameters, they can not be virtual, and are always private.

More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Unimplemented partial methods are removed at compile time. A compiler can ignore a call to void methods because they only modify state of an already existing object. It cannot remove methods that return objects because that would invalidate the code.